# img onClick doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

I have got problem with this `<img onClick="close()" src="img/close.png">`, and this is close function

```
function close(n){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

I don't know why but when I click that image, nothing happens, when I try close() in console it works. I even tried to do `<a href="#" onClick="close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>` but nothing happened. Anyone know where's the problem? I have no clue where the problem may be.

I tried to add it on JSfiddle but it works less http://jsfiddle.net/hHe2w/5/

Comment: It could be a typo. try `onclick` instead of `onClick`

Comment: 1) it's just `onclick` without capitals. 2) the function `close(n)` expects an argument `n`, but in the HTML-onclick you're not sending along anything

Comment: onclick instead onClick? That's weird because other onClicks are working.

Comment: Have you checked your console? Is `close` declared globally or within another function?

Comment: " when I try close() in console it works"

Comment: @soktinpk if it is declared within function it would not call from console :)

Comment: That overlay, is that over the image by any chance? Because than obviously you won't be able to click the image

Comment: And you have just one 'overlay' id?

Comment: I (We) think you need to give us some more code, a little bit of context. It could be anything but we can't figure it out if we don't have all the information..

Comment: try `return false;` inside your `close()` function to prevent default action of `<a>` tag and `<img onclick="return close()" src="img/close.png">`

Comment: #overlay has z-index 100 and that img has z-index 1000, so that shouldnt be proble in my opinion, also I added http://jsfiddle.net/hHe2w/3/ but JSFiddle is not working correctly.

Comment: @user3719693 - better put that fiddle in your question

Comment: @myfunkside http://jsfiddle.net/hHe2w/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems close is a reserved keyword.

Try -

```
function closeMe(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ny3Nf/)

A few typos are causing the issue:

1. you are calling the close function on ID in your HTML
2. overlay is already hidden and you are again trying to hide it.

Check this [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hHe2w/4/) and arrange your HTML accordingly

Comment: No difference, sadly.

Comment: @user3719693 check the fiddle

Comment: In ifddle it works but not in my case, I think there is a problem in my CSS with that close button, check my fiddle above.

Comment: You avoided the problem with moving close button to place where it's alone and looks awfull, my overlay is showed by clicking anything in menu (which doesnt work on jsfiddle but works locally), here is fiddle with showed overlay http://jsfiddle.net/hHe2w/5/.

Comment: it works but there is a question then, my javascript is working without any problem, but it's not working if it's like this <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>, how do I fix that, so I can keep my JS in external file?

Comment: @user3719693 - Check my answer, I used your fiddle and left it in external file

Comment: It will work only pay attention to the onclick <img onclick="closeOverlay()" because you are writing <img id="closeOverlay()" which is wrong

Answer (score 3):

`close()` is native method of the global `window` object so when using inline code in the HTML itself, it will take precedence in some browsers.

Change the function name to something more meaningful, e.g.

```
function HideOverlay(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

And change the call too of course, and it will work.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhH3Q/).

Better practice would be using only JavaScript to define the click event:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("imgHideOverflow").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
    };
};
```

No messing around with JS inside the HTML itself. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhH3Q/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<someElement id="overlay">...</someElement>
<img onClick="close()" src="img/close.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function close(){
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

Make sure you write `close()` and not `close(n)`.

Comment: In theory, it shouldn't matter because `n` would be undefined, and since he doesn't use n, it won't solve his problem (probably)

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle works when onLoad has been changed for head.

In your case, you tried to assign a javascript function which doesn't exist onDom ready.

Try to put javascript in html head

Answer (score 0):

Oke here, it works: **http://jsfiddle.net/PCN65/**

What I did is

1. I changed `id="close()"` to `onclick="closeOverlay()"`.
2. I removed the `;` from behind your function, they should not be there.
3. I changed the "onLoad" in jsFiddle to "No Wrap - in head". What happens when you put onLoad in jsFiddle is this:

`window.onload = function(){
    function closeOverlay(){
        //code
    }
};`

This makes the closeOverlay-function anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

```
function close(){document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";}
  // no param for event

function close(e) // e ist event, but you need a string for getelementById()
{document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";}

<img onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('overlay').style.display="none";" src="img/close.png">
                  // better, no event handler function
```

style.display and style.visibility are not the same

IE visibility Attribute | visibility

```
syntax
    HTML        { visibility : sVisibility }  
    Scripting   object.style.visibility [ = sVisibility ] 

    sVisibility     String  "inherit" Default.
                "visible"
                "hidden"
    object can not loses place in document
```

IE display Attribute | display

```
syntax
    HTML        { display : sDisplay }  
    Scripting   object.style.display [ = sDisplay ] 

    sDisplay String     "block"
                "none"      object loses place in document
                "inline"
                "inline-block"
                "list-item"
                "table-header-group" 
                "table-footer-group"
```